# Choose which is the default program to open when you plugin a camera via USB on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

How do you choose which is the default program to open when you plugin a camera via USB on a Mac OS X computer?

Answer (score 5):

In OSX you can use the Image Capture application to import photos from cameras and media. In that app, select the device and on the bottom of the sidebar you can change what program launches when you connect a device. Just hit Apple Command and Space Bar, then type in Image Capture and press Enter - this will launch the program. The device needs to be connected to adjust the import settings, so attach you camera or SD card if it is not.

See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RuvXLand3ys) for a tutorial.

You can also [change the setting within iPhoto](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2500).

Answer (score 2):

You can also download  [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/), which replaces the settings that have disappeared from OS X over the past few years - where you can choose this and many other defaults. Still runs just fine under Mountain Lion.